# shorting method of current source and voltage source

Tags: electrical

I'm learning electronic circuit and sometimes we need to short just the current sources and sometimes we want to short source voltage. my question is: why if I want to short the current source then we must cut/disconnet the current source, and if I want to short the voltage source I just short it and not disconnect it.

why for example can't short the current source? if I short it then the current will not go to the circuit it will just loop where I've shorted it (so we don't have current on my circuit and just have yeah current on the wire short that shorted the current source, but we can call that we shorted the current source because we don't have current pass to the circuit, so why we are not using this for shorting the current source? instead of disconnecting it?!!

Comment: I think you'd better use a verb like 'disable' in the first sentence: *...sometimes we need to disable the current sources and sometimes we want to disable the source voltage*. I you 'short' a circuit, you make it 'short'er than the original circuit/wiring.

Comment: What is "yeah current"? Can you tidy up your capitalisation to improve legibility? Posts with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get read and upvoted more frequently. Remember, you can always go back at any time and edit your post to improve it. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages.

Comment: If you short a real voltage source (apply a short circuit as its load) you'll send it into some kind of nonlinear behavior. Either it catches fire or it shuts itself off. Or possibly you find out your short isn't really a short.

Answer (score 2):

Because you want to reduce the source, be it current or voltage, to zero.  A zero-voltage source is a short circuit.  A zero-current source is an **open** circuit.  So when you set the current to zero you *do not* **short** the current source -- you open it.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the design of a current source, it may stay at the same current but now have the input voltage drop and resulting in all the power overheating the current source.

However, a well-designed power supply or low constant current source can handle a short to ground or a CC sink to supply.

[Here you can short this all you want.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.0008049999999999999%2010.20027730826997%2058%205%2050%0Aa%200%20160%20112%20160%208%2015%20-15%201000000%20-0.9999100053996761%20-0.9999400035997841%20100000%0Aw%20112%20160%20112%2096%200%0Aw%20112%20160%20112%20224%203%0Ar%200%20224%20112%20224%200%201000%0Ar%200%2096%20112%2096%200%205000%0Ar%200%2096%20-112%2096%200%205000%0Ar%20-112%20224%200%20224%200%201000%0Aw%200%20176%200%20224%202%0AR%20-112%2096%20-112%2048%200%200%2040%201%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20-112%20224%20-112%20256%200%0Aw%200%2096%200%20144%202%0Aw%200%20224%200%20272%201%0Ar%200%20272%200%20352%200%201000%0As%2048%20272%2048%20352%200%201%20false%0Aw%200%20352%2048%20352%200%0Ag%200%20352%200%20384%200%0Aw%200%20272%2048%20272%200%0Ax%20-69%2067%20-39%2070%204%2024%20R1%0Ax%2044%2067%2074%2070%204%2024%20R2%0Ax%20-71%20259%20-41%20262%204%2024%20R3%0Ax%2042%20259%2072%20262%204%2024%20R4%0Ax%2072%20321%20236%20324%204%2024%20Short%5Csload%5Cshere%0At%20480%20208%20432%20208%200%201%20-0.7717196476359138%200.5498892104648974%20100%0At%20432%20160%20480%20160%200%201%20-0.3050893868774871%200.7717196476359138%20100%0Aw%20480%20176%20480%20208%201%0Aw%20432%20224%20432%20256%200%0Ar%20480%20208%20480%20256%200%200.6%0Aw%20432%20256%20480%20256%200%0Aw%20432%20160%20432%20192%200%0Ar%20432%20160%20432%20112%200%2033%0Aw%20480%20144%20480%20112%200%0Aw%20480%20112%20432%20112%200%0AR%20480%20112%20480%2080%200%200%2040%2012%200%200%200.5%0A181%20480%20272%20480%20336%200%202356.1633210625923%2012%2012%200.4%200.4%0Ag%20480%20336%20480%20352%200%0Ax%20552%20305%20778%20308%204%2024%20Don't%5CsShort%5Csload%5Cshere%0Ax%20438%20247%20468%20250%204%2024%20R4%0Aw%20480%20256%20528%20256%200%0Aw%20480%20336%20528%20336%200%0As%20528%20256%20528%20336%200%201%20false%0Aw%20480%20208%20544%20208%200%0Aw%20528%20256%20544%20256%200%0Ap%20544%20208%20544%20256%201%200%0Aw%20432%20256%20384%20256%202%0A403%20496%20112%20624%20176%200%2023_64_7_4354_20_0.1_0_1_5%0A403%20320%20288%20448%20352%200%2033_64_2_4354_20_0.1_0_1_20%0A403%20416%200%20544%2064%200%2032_64_0_4865_20_1.6_0_2_32_3%0Aw%20480%20256%20480%20272%201%0Ax%20394%20408%20788%20411%204%2024%20Soft%5Csstart%5CsCurrent%5Cslimiter%5Cs(press%5Csreset)%0A)

Comment: Did I misunderstand your question or did someone misunderstand my answer or both?